# Use if-condition in string template

Tags: string, list, if-statement, structure, abap

My Problem is to integrate an if-statement into a string template.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_field,
         name   TYPE string,
         label  TYPE string,
         result TYPE string,
       END OF ty_field.
DATA: mt_fields TYPE TABLE OF ty_field.

mt_fields = VALUE #(
        ( name = 'HI'      label = 'Greeting' )
        ( name = 'PERSON'  label = 'Who' )
        ( name = 'RESULT'  label = 'Sentence'  result = |Say \{HI\} to \{PERSON\}.| ) ).
```

Unfortunately the line 3 of `mt_fields` has `result` set to `Say {HI} to {PERSON}` but I'd expect `Say Greeting to Who`.

More importantly, **what I want to get**:
Some times there is no data for `PERSON`. In that case, the result variable will get the string `'Say hello to .'` (if `'hello'` is the value for `HI`).

I dont want to have this. If there is no person, I want to get an empty string as result. So I have to filter first, whether there is some value for `PERSON` or not. I need to get an if-condition into the string assignment.

In Python I would write something like

```
( name = 'RESULT'  label = 'Sentence'  result = 'Say {HI} to {PERSON}.' IF PERSON != '' ELSE '' )
```

But how to do this in ABAP?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the COND statement is what you need https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abenconditional_expression_cond.htm

Comment: Your ABAP code doesn't compile and so doesn't produce `Say Greeting to Who`. Even if I understand what you want to achieve, I can't provide any correction because there's no valid original code to correct. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please declare the variables and so on.

Comment: @SandraRossi: My question is not about that example. It is in general: How can I integrate an if condition into a string assignment?

In Python I would write `variable = "abc" if condition else "xyz"`. This is what I need for ABAP.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to do:

```
    TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_field,
             name   TYPE string,
             label  TYPE string,
             result TYPE string,
           END OF ty_field.
    DATA: mt_fields TYPE TABLE OF ty_field.

    mt_fields = VALUE #( let salutation = 'Greeting' pers = cond string( when salutation = 'Hello' then '' else 'Who' ) IN
                          ( name = 'HI'      label = salutation )
                          ( name = 'PERSON'  label = pers )
                          ( name = 'RESULT'  label = 'Sentence'  result = |Say { salutation } to { pers }.| ) ).
```